# Skipping aggressive release due to manual disabling

Tags: hibernate

I am getting the following DEBUG message from hibernate in my log:

```
DEBUG [JdbcCoordinatorImpl] Skipping aggressive release due to manual disabling
```

Which is probably fine, because it's just a debug message. But I do not understand what it means. Can someone explain this debug message for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have configured hibernate to return connnection to the pool after the each statement that is run (this is what the log message means with 'aggressive release'). The default is to keep the connection during the whole transaction.

the documentation of this parameter : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-connection-release.html

But hibernate decided not to return it this time (and shows of this log message), because there is a flush operation in progress, and hibernate will keep the connection for all sql statements that will happen during the flush.